# Handling multiple UDP sockets listening on the same endpoint

Tags: c#, c, sockets, udp, dtls

I've been following (roughly) some example code [here](https://github.com/nplab/DTLS-Examples/blob/master/src/dtls_udp_echo.c) on writing a DTLS server that can handle multiple clients. In this example, which works quite well (I tried), the server listens on `INADDR_ANY` and port `0`.

```
fd = socket(server_addr.ss.ss_family, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void*) &on, (socklen_t) sizeof(on));
bind(fd, (const struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))
```

When a DGRAM is received, the server runs it through an OpenSSL method to generate a cookie and verify the client is *actually* at the address they say they are. Once that's done, the server **creates a new socket bound to the same endpoint and does `connect()` to the new client's endpoint.**

```
bind(fd, (const struct sockaddr *) &pinfo->server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))
connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &pinfo->client_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))
```

So at this point, there are 2 UDP sockets bound to the *same IP address and port*. One of them is `connect()`ed and the other is only bound.

I've tried to do the same thing (in C#):

```
_sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
_sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
_sock.Bind(localEp);

var clientEndpoint = await DtlsListenAsync(ssl, _sock);

var clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
clientSock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
clientSock.Bind(_localEp);
clientSock.Connect(clientEndpoint);
```

Keep in mind, I've edited out most of the code for brevity.

At this point, running *my* application fails miserably. It seems the socket created for the client never gets the messages. Basically any call to `await clientSock.ReceiveAsync()` hangs indefinitely.

*However*, if I debug and **step through** the code works. This leads me to believe that its a "race" between the sockets. Basically, can the client socket be created, bound and connected before the next DGRAM comes in and gets sent to the *original* socket.

AFAIK, UDP sockets work on a *score* system. The kernel calculates a score based on how specific the rout is for a given DGRAM and sends it to the highest scoring socket. So, it seems to me that my server should work as well as the example... But it doesn't.

So I'm not really asking if my *code* is right per se, but I'd like to know if what I'm trying to do makes any sense. Also if there are any considerations I haven't taken into account. Do sockets behave as I mentioned?

My alternative if this method doesn't pan out is to use a single socket and maintain a hashtable of endpoints and dispatch the data to the appropriate client as it comes in. But TBH, I really like the idea of leveraging sockets to do the "heavy lifting" for me.

Comment: The only way you can guarantee that kind of ordering is if the higher layer protocol implements stop-and-wait.  Maybe you'd better implement dispatching packets from the base socket even if you open new sockets to shortcut future packets.

Comment: For the server to 'connect()` to the client, the client must have executed `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()` and `accept()`.   Note: port 0 is a very bad idea to use for communication.  Infact any port number less than 1024 is a very bad idea.  [port numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) gives the usage of the 'reserved' port numbers (0...1023)  In general, to communicate on those ports, the 'firewall' must be set to allow that communication

Comment: @user3629249 we are talking about udp here.... And port 0 is neither a bad nor a good idea. It allows the socket engine to choose an ephemeral port. If that suits the application, then it should be used.

Comment: @user3629249 Evidently you have never heard of `connect()` for UDP.

Comment: @user207421 The only thing `connect()` does for UDP sockets is add a default address so you can use `send()` instead of `sendto()` for UDP packets. `snedto()` can *still* be used to send a packet anywhere. `connect()` on UDP sockets has zero impact on where packets will be read via `recv[from]()`, and `accept()` and `listen()` are still completely not applicable to UDP sockets.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Actually it does a little more than that. After using `connect()` on a UDP socket you can then use `recv()` and it will receive packets from the connected endpoint only. It's useful because then you don't have to keep state in your application to direct traffic from specific endpoints, you can pass around the `connect`ed socket and let the kernel do the work. There are a few caveats but generally it's not too hard to implement. The reason my code didn't work in C# is because the .net runtime sets `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT` where it should *not* be setting `SO_REUSEPORT`