# Problems using UDP sockets bound to the same port on Windows

Tags: c, windows, sockets, udp

I think that my issue is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281657/handling-multiple-udp-sockets-listening-on-the-same-endpoint) which never got answered. In my case, I have a large, multi-threaded server application that communicates using UDP. Every client that connects to the server gets its own UDP socket and thread. In one particular use-case, it's very advantageous to have all of these sockets bound to the same local address and port, but connected to different destination addresses. On macOS and Linux, this works great, but it doesn't work on Windows.

The easiest way to illustrate the problem is to compare it to TCP. Let's assume that every socket is a 5-tuple `(protocol, src_addr, src_port, dst_addr, dst_port)`. If I call `listen()` on port `5000` and then do an `accept()`, I wind up with something like the following situation:

- listen socket: `(TCP, 0.0.0.0, 5000, 0.0.0.0, 0)`
- accept socket: `(TCP, 10.1.1.1, 5000, 10.2.2.2, 12345)`

which can be confirmed with `netstat` (this one's on a mac, but Windows looks similar):

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.220.5000     192.168.1.220.65282    ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  *.5000                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

When incoming packets are received, they are given to the "best" matching socket and fall back to the listen socket if there's no better match. This happens on all platforms.

To do the same thing with UDP, I create the "listen" socket by setting `SO_REUSEPORT` or `SO_REUSEADDR` (depending on the platform), then calling `bind()`. The "accept" socket can be made using `SO_REUSEPORT`, `bind()`, then calling `connect()` to set its destination address. Which gives a similar situation:

- "listen" socket: `(UDP, 0.0.0.0, 5000, 0.0.0.0, 0)`
- "accept" socket: `(UDP, 10.1.1.1, 5000, 10.2.2.2, 12345)`

again confirmed by `netstat` (on a mac):

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
udp4       0      0  10.211.55.2.5000       10.211.55.2.6666                  
udp4       0      0  *.5000                 *.*
```

On macOS and Linux, incoming packets go to the "best" socket just like with TCP. But on Windows, packets are always dispatched to the first socket, completely ignoring the `connect()`. The call to `connect()` really did bind to both a local and foreign address (verified with `getsockname()` and `getpeername()`), but even `netstat` thinks the 2 sockets are the same:

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5000           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5000           *:*
```

I find this strange since it works on other platforms, it works with TCP, and `netstat` doesn't show the real bound addresses. It's almost as if `connect()` is doing filtering at a higher level and it's never making its way down to the network drivers.

I realize that I could just open a single socket and handle the dispatching myself, but it's a pain since there are lots of threads that can currently act independently and that would add a single sync point, as well as adding an extra layer of buffering. Ideally there would be an easy way to convince Windows to just treat UDP dispatching the same way as everything else.

Here is a minimal working example that compiles and runs on macOS (clang/llvm), Linux (gcc), and Windows (Visual Studio). Error handling has been omitted for brevity. Note that I'm explicitly using an external address since `localhost` is special and isn't relevant to my use-case. The sample code creates 2 sockets on local port 9999, one of which is also connected to a hardcoded IP address on port 6666. I then send a packet to each socket using something like:

```
echo 1 | nc -w 1 -u 10.211.55.9 9999 && echo 2 | nc -w 1 -p 6666 -u 10.211.55.9 9999
```

On Linux and macOS this gives:

```
Socket listen got packet [49] from [0ad33702:56651].
Socket accept got packet [50] from [0ad33702:6666].
```

but on Windows I get:

```
Socket listen got packet [49] from [0ad33702:58940].
Socket listen got packet [50] from [0ad33702:6666].
```

Here's the C program. There a bit of boiler-plate, but `main()` should hopefully be self-explanatory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
typedef SOCKET SocketHandle;
static int poll(struct pollfd *fds, unsigned long nfds, int timeout) { return WSAPoll(fds, nfds, timeout); } // rename WSAPoll to poll
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#else
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
typedef int SocketHandle;
#endif

// Explicitly send data to an external IP address, not localhost. In this case 10.211.55.2. Change as needed.
static uint32_t sIpAddr = 10u<<24 | 211u<<16 | 55u<<8 | 2u;

static void setReusePort(SocketHandle s)
{
    int trueval = 1;
    #ifdef SO_REUSEPORT
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (const char*) &trueval, sizeof(trueval));
    #else
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*) &trueval, sizeof(trueval));
    #endif
}

static void bindSocket(SocketHandle s, uint32_t addr, uint16_t port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in sourceAddr;
    memset(&sourceAddr, 0, sizeof(sourceAddr));
    sourceAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sourceAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(addr);
    sourceAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
#ifdef __APPLE__
    sourceAddr.sin_len = sizeof(sourceAddr);
#endif
    bind(s, (const struct sockaddr*) &sourceAddr, sizeof(sourceAddr));
}

static void connectSocket(SocketHandle s, uint32_t addr, uint16_t port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in peerAddr;
    memset(&peerAddr, 0, sizeof(peerAddr));
    peerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    peerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(addr);
    peerAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
#ifdef __APPLE__
    peerAddr.sin_len = sizeof(addr);
#endif
    connect(s, (const struct sockaddr*) &peerAddr, sizeof(peerAddr));
}

static void receive(SocketHandle s, const char* name)
{
    struct sockaddr_in retAddr;
    memset(&retAddr, 0, sizeof(retAddr));
    retAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
#ifdef __APPLE__
    retAddr.sin_len = sizeof(retAddr);
#endif
    socklen_t retAddrLen = sizeof(retAddr);

    // Recv up to 10 packets over 10 seconds.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        struct pollfd pollSet = {s, POLLRDNORM, 0};
        int r = poll(&pollSet, 1, 1000);
        if (1 == r && POLLRDNORM == (pollSet.revents & POLLRDNORM)) {
            char data[256];
            if (recvfrom(s, data, (int) sizeof(data), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &retAddr, &retAddrLen) > 0) {
                printf("Socket %s got packet [%u] from [%8.8x:%u].\n", name, (unsigned int)data[0], ntohl(retAddr.sin_addr.s_addr), ntohs(retAddr.sin_port));
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA data;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);
#endif

    // Create a UDP socket on port 9999 (essentially the "listen" socket).
    SocketHandle s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    setReusePort(s);
    bindSocket(s, INADDR_ANY, 9999);

    // At this point, all incoming packets on port 9999 are delivered to `s`.

    // Create another UDP socket on port 9999 (will be the "accept" socket).
    SocketHandle s2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    setReusePort(s2);
    bindSocket(s2, INADDR_ANY, 9999);

    // At this point, all incoming packets on port 9999 are still delivered to `s`.

    // Restrict `s2` to only communicate with a particular address ("accept").
    connectSocket(s2, sIpAddr, 6666);

    // At this point, things are different between platforms:
    // Linux/BSD: packets from 10.211.55.2:6666 are delivered to `s2`, everything else to `s`
    // Windows: all packets still delivered to `s`
    receive(s, "listen");
    receive(s2, "accept");

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know how Windows handles this dispatching and if there a `setsockopt` or `WSAIoctl` or similar to work around it?

Comment: "I create the "listen" socket by calling bind(), then setting SO_REUSEPORT or SO_REUSEADDR." This is exactly the wrong order. You have to set the option before binding.

Comment: @user207421 Quite right. The sample code was right but the prose was wrong. Will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
typedef SOCKET SocketHandle;
static int poll(struct pollfd *fds, unsigned long nfds, int timeout) { return WSAPoll(fds, nfds, timeout); } // rename WSAPoll to poll
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#else
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
typedef int SocketHandle;
#endif

// Explicitly send data to an external IP address, not localhost. In this case 10.211.55.2. Change as needed.
static uint32_t sIpAddr = 10u<<24 | 211u<<16 | 55u<<8 | 2u;

static void setReusePort(SocketHandle s)
{
    int trueval = 1;
    #ifdef SO_REUSEPORT
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (const char*) &trueval, sizeof(trueval));
    #else
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*) &trueval, sizeof(trueval));
    #endif
}

static void bindSocket(SocketHandle s, uint32_t addr, uint16_t port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in sourceAddr;
    memset(&sourceAddr, 0, sizeof(sourceAddr));
    sourceAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sourceAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(addr);
    sourceAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
#ifdef __APPLE__
    sourceAddr.sin_len = sizeof(sourceAddr);
#endif
    bind(s, (const struct sockaddr*) &sourceAddr, sizeof(sourceAddr));
}

static void connectSocket(SocketHandle s, uint32_t addr, uint16_t port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in peerAddr;
    memset(&peerAddr, 0, sizeof(peerAddr));
    peerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    peerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(addr);
    peerAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
#ifdef __APPLE__
    peerAddr.sin_len = sizeof(addr);
#endif
    connect(s, (const struct sockaddr*) &peerAddr, sizeof(peerAddr));
}

static void receiveFrom(SocketHandle s, const char* name)
{
    struct sockaddr_in retAddr;
    memset(&retAddr, 0, sizeof(retAddr));
    retAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
#ifdef __APPLE__
    retAddr.sin_len = sizeof(retAddr);
#endif
    socklen_t retAddrLen = sizeof(retAddr);

    // Recv up to 10 packets over 10 seconds.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        struct pollfd pollSet = {s, POLLRDNORM, 0};
        int r = poll(&pollSet, 1, 1000);
        if (1 == r && POLLRDNORM == (pollSet.revents & POLLRDNORM)) {
            char data[256];
            if (recvfrom(s, data, (int) sizeof(data), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &retAddr, &retAddrLen) > 0) {
                printf("Socket %s got packet [%u] from [%8.8x:%u].\n", name, (unsigned int)data[0], ntohl(retAddr.sin_addr.s_addr), ntohs(retAddr.sin_port));
            }
        }
    }
}

static void receive(SocketHandle s, const char* name)
{
    struct sockaddr_in retAddr;
    memset(&retAddr, 0, sizeof(retAddr));
    retAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
#ifdef __APPLE__
    retAddr.sin_len = sizeof(retAddr);
#endif
    socklen_t retAddrLen = sizeof(retAddr);

    // Recv up to 10 packets over 10 seconds.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        struct pollfd pollSet = {s, POLLRDNORM, 0};
        int r = poll(&pollSet, 1, 1000);
        if (1 == r && POLLRDNORM == (pollSet.revents & POLLRDNORM)) {
            char data[256];
            if (recv(s, data, (int) sizeof(data), 0) > 0) {
                printf("Socket %s got packet [%u].\n", name, (unsigned int)data[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA data;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);
#endif

    // Create a UDP socket on port 9999 (essentially the "listen" socket).
    SocketHandle s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    setReusePort(s);
    bindSocket(s, INADDR_ANY, 9999);
    receiveFrom(s, "listen");
    connectSocket(s, sIpAddr, 6666);
    
    // At this point, all incoming packets on port 9999 are delivered to `s`.
    // Create another UDP socket on port 9999 (will be the "accept" socket).
    SocketHandle s2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    setReusePort(s2);
    bindSocket(s2, INADDR_ANY, 9999);

    // At this point, all incoming packets on port 9999 are still delivered to `s`.

    // Restrict `s2` to only communicate with a particular address ("accept").

    // At this point, things are different between platforms:
    // Linux/BSD: packets from 10.211.55.2:6666 are delivered to `s2`, everything else to `s`
    // Windows: all packets still delivered to `s`
    receive(s, "accept");
    receiveFrom(s2, "listen");
    
    return 0;
}
```

**test command line**

```
echo 2 | nc -w 1 -p 6666 -u 10.211.55.9 9999 && echo 1 | nc -w 1 -u 10.211.55.9 9999 && echo 3 | nc -w 1 -p 6666 -u 10.211.55.9 9999
```

Comment: Essentially this change opens the connected socket first, then opens the unconnected socket. I tested your change and found that the first opened socket (the one that called `connect` in this case) is still the only socket getting data. The connected socket receives data sent to its port, but the unconnected socket gets no data at all. I confirmed the result by receiving on both sockets in a loop and can see that the first one is the only was successfully getting data.

Answer (score -1):

I have encounter this problem. MSDN has this to say about [`connect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect):

> For a connectionless socket (for example, type SOCK_DGRAM), the operation performed by connect is merely to establish a default destination address that can be used on subsequent send/ WSASend and recv/ WSARecv calls. Any datagrams received from an address other than the destination address specified will be discarded. If the address member of the structure specified by name is filled with zeros, the socket will be disconnected. Then, the default remote address will be indeterminate, so send/ WSASend and recv/ WSARecv calls will return the error code WSAENOTCONN. However, sendto/ WSASendTo and recvfrom/ WSARecvFrom can still be used. The default destination can be changed by simply calling connect again, even if the socket is already connected. Any datagrams queued for receipt are discarded if name is different from the previous connect.

So i think udp five tuple will preference with first time it has been received socket,so i use udp server socket to connect remote address, and create an other udp socket as the udp server, this work fine

Comment: I provided the missing attribution for you. If you quote, provide a citation. I don't see anything here that actually answers the question. It just repeats what the OP is already doing.