# Only one socket receives data. Two UDP server sockets bound to same port, different addresses on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, udp

**[Similar Questions]:**

[Problems using UDP sockets bound to the same port on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779711/)

[Handling multiple UDP sockets listening on the same endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281657/)

None of which ever got resolved.

**[Situation]:**

On Microsoft Windows, I bind two UDP server sockets in the same process. This particular (not to say peculiar) operating system supports only `SO_REUSEADDR`, it does not support `SO_REUSEPORT`; and on top of that, `SO_REUSEADDR` acts like `SO_REUSEPORT`.

So, considering the above, I am left with binding socket A to `0.0.0.0:1234` and socket B to say `192.168.1.1:1234`; if I'm to reuse the same port on the same machine.

Namely, I **cannot** bind both to the same IP address, since Microsoft Windows would not agree with that; since yet again, it **does not** support two sockets to be bound to exactly the same tuple of `{SRC_ADDR,DST_ADDR, SRC_PORT,DST_PORT,PROTOCOL}` even when `SO_REUSEADDR` is used on BOTH sockets.

So, I'm forced to bind to two distinct addresses, if I'm to use the same port on the same machine. Even though `0.0.0.0` represents any address, but in any case Microsoft Windows agrees, and binds the two sockets in such a configuration, without any error.

The binding operations, in such a configuration for the two UDP sockets, **do succeed.**

**Problem:**

Now, I'm having trouble getting these sockets to receive data as expected. Namely, I expect the two sockets to receive data. In reality, only the socket which got bound first receives data.

Any ideas?

Is it that the data is always received by the socket best matching the destination? If you wonder why I'm playing that way, it's because I'm trying to multiplex two libraries with two protocols over the same port, with the least amount of modifications.

Comment: Which IP(s) are actually installed on the machine, and which IP is the UDP packet being sent to? If a packet is sent to `192.168.1.1:1234`, it is going to be a better match for the socket bound to `192.168.1.1:1234` than the one bound to `0.0.0.0:1234`. A packet is sent to a specific IP/port. If you are expecting both sockets to bind to the same port on different IPs and yet receive the same packet, regardless of which IP it is actually sent to, then that is simply not how UDP or ports actually work.

Answer (score -1):

If you want two ports are received same udp packet you should set option/flag broadcast for transmit socket.
Something like:

```
      socket_.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true));
```

In some cases (for some OS's) you should transmit packet to broadcast address instead of exact ip-address.